# Protected mode and Real mode

Tags: cpu

What happens when we switch from protected mode to real mode?
From what i'v learned by googling, i know Real mode is available in CPUs to allow
some of the old applications to run properly without the need to be rewritten.
But nowadays it is nonsense to run old applications on moder systems. Is there any other reason that CPU manufacturers still support this mode? I know when we turn our computers on it start with Real mode, but it should not be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Real Mode is there for the BIOS and POST phase and for OSes that don't need Protected Mode,
there are cases out there where enabling the extra memory protection only makes it more complex.